# Adding dynamic ListView to fragment (specific project)

Tags: android, listview, fragment, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to figure out how to implement a dynamic ListView into a fragment, but can't figure it out. This project uses a custom ArrayAdapter.

[Custom ListView with custom adapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

I figured I would link the tutorial page instead of just pasting everything over. How would I go about making this work in a fragment page?

**FeaturedDealsFragment.java (fragment class)**

```
public class FeaturedDealsFragment extends Fragment {

@Override  
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_featured_deals, container, false);

    ListView LV = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Deal deal_data[] = new Deal[]
            {
                new Deal("Deal 1", R.drawable.scenery, "500/100 Supporters", "$500"),
                new Deal("Deal 2", R.drawable.scenery, "500/100 Supporters", "$500"),
                new Deal("Deal 3", R.drawable.scenery, "500/100 Supporters", "$500"),
                new Deal("Deal 4", R.drawable.scenery, "500/100 Supporters", "$500"),
                new Deal("Deal 5", R.drawable.scenery, "500/100 Supporters", "$500")
            };

    DealAdapter adapter = new DealAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item_row, deal_data);

    View header = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    LV.addHeaderView(header);
    LV.setAdapter(adapter);

    return V;

}

}
```

**DealAdapter.java**

```
public class DealAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Deal>{

Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
Deal data[] = null;

public DealAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Deal[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    DealHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new DealHolder();
        holder.txtDeal = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtDeal);
        holder.imgDealImage = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgDealImage);
        holder.txtSupporters = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtSupporters);
        holder.txtPrice = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (DealHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Deal deal = data[position];
    holder.txtDeal.setText(deal.deal);
    holder.imgDealImage.setImageResource(deal.image);
    holder.txtSupporters.setText(deal.supporters);
    holder.txtPrice.setText(deal.price);

    return row;
}

static class DealHolder
{
    TextView txtDeal;
    ImageView imgDealImage;
    TextView txtSupporters;
    TextView txtPrice;
}
}
```

**Deal.java**

```
public class Deal {
public String deal;
public int image;
public String supporters;
public String price;

public Deal() {
    super();
}

public Deal(String deal, int image, String supporters, String price) {
    super();
    this.deal = deal;
    this.image = image;
    this.supporters = supporters;
    this.price = price;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling getLayoutInflater() which is a method in the Activity class, just use the LayoutInflater that is passed into your onCreateView method:

```
View header = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
```

A Fragment isn't a subclass of Context. The easiest way to get a reference to a Context object is usually by getting a reference to an Activity which is a subclass of Context. Therefore you need to change the WeatherAdapter to:

```
WeatherAdapter adapter = new WeatherAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);
```

Comment: I added the WeatherAdapter class code above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated and tidied answer. I hope it helps :)

Comment: This solved my issues of having errors, but still crashes when I run it. Please see above, I edited the code a little bit, but same format. Just added two more TextViews when I populate it. Also, changed "Weather" into "Deal".

Comment: Can you please post the error message you are receiving? There should be a red error message in your LogCat window in Eclipse.

Comment: There's more too... is there an easier way to show where the problem is?

Comment: In the future you will need to limit the scope of your problems so that only one problem is posted per StackOverflow question. This way people that have a similar problem to you can find the answer to their problems. After this please make a new question if you are still having problems and include relevant code and errors in your post. In this case, your problem is a NullPointerException in line 30 of your FeaturedDealsFragment class (specifically in the onCreateView method) Take a look at that line.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry about that. Will try a new post. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want an Activity which contains a fragment which contains a ListView.

The right way is to create a Fragment and add to its layout a ListView. In its onCreateView method get the ListView reference and sets your adapter.

In the activity you can add the Fragment via XML layout or in the onCreate method programatically.

I do not know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. I already have the fragment pages setup, but I am trying to add the ListView to the fragment. I added my code in the fragment above. there is an error in the WeatherAdapter line: "The constructor WeatherAdapter is undefined". And the line below that, View header says: "The method getLayoutInflater(Bundle) in type Fragment is not applicable for the arguments".